# Unable to connect to localhost port to debug Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, .net-core, localhost

I am using a mac and visual studio 2019, dotnet 2.2 and when I try to run my any app including a new template I am unable to connect to local host in the browser. [image]

I have tried delete and re-adding the local host certificates multiple times, I have uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio, dotnet and Chrome. I'm really at a loss of what to do. Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks. I am getting this in the output in Visual Studio when I run the app:
[image]

These messages are coming up while the app is running.

Comment: Did you change application port and run again project?

Comment: Try to run your application with `--urls http://localhost:5000` and use your browser to test that HTTP link instead. Only then you know what might be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure your browser is going to HTTPS://localhost:5001? It doesn't look like.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked when I deactivated the "Enable SSL" in my problem.